# sed command not working while executing C file

Tags: c, regex, sed

I have the following files and content

*1.txt*

```
fruit="mango"
```

*C file*

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   char *cmd=NULL;
   system("sed  -c -i  /^[[:blank:]]*fruit[[:blank:]]*=/s/=.*/=\"apple\"/  1.txt");
}
```

> o/p has to be fruit="apple"
>       but it is displaying fruit=apple (double quotes are not coming)

when i try the command separately as Linux command it is showing with double quotes.

Comment: `system` runs the command via the shell, which may be eating your double quotes. Try putting the whole sed command parameter in single quotes like this: `'/^[[:blank:]]*fruit[[:blank:]]*=/s/=.*/=\"apple\"/'`.

Comment: Alternatively, change `\"` to `\\\"` in both places on your `system` command in order to pass the `\"` on the command line. At the moment, the `\"` just produces `"` because `\"` is the C escape sequence for the `"` character. `\\` is the C escape sequence for the `\` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a C string literal, `\"` is the escape sequence for the `"` character. It looks like you want to escape the `"` character with the `\` character in the shell as well.  In order to do that, you should write it as `\\\"` in your C string literal.  The `\\` in the string literal source produces a single `\` in the actual string object (array of `char`). The `\"` in the string literal source produces a `"` in the actual string object.